# My rows are wonky!

Tags: posts, themes, templates

I am building a theme template page that calls up all the child categories of a particular parent and displays them so that they look like this: [image]

**The only trouble** is that when any row has less than 3 posts, it looks like this:

[image]

I need to display 1-3 posts and move on to the next category if there are either more OR less than 3 posts, and not have it look like crap.

```
$taxonomy = 'category'; //  e.g. post_tag, category
$param_type = 'category__in'; //  e.g. tag__in, category__in
$term_args=array(
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'child_of' => 13
);
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy,$term_args);
if ($terms) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        $args=array(
            "$param_type" => array($term->term_id),
            'post_type' => 'candidate',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'showposts' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<div class="val-postcontent val-post"><h4 >' . $term->name. ' Candidates</h4></div> ';    
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();      
                get_template_part('content', 'overview');
            endwhile;                
            echo '<div class="test"><a  href="' . get_category_link( $term->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $term->name ) . '" ' . '>Click here to view all ' . $term->name. ' Candidates</a></div>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, then this is more of a CSS issue. Consider Inspecting Element and adjusting your 3 post display.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think it is css. Seems like some sort of counter is needed to tell it jump to the next category.

Comment: show us your content-overview.php file

Comment: I'll try.... there's not much to it though <?php

global $post;
$test=types_render_field("party", array("argument1"=>"value1","argument2"=>"value2"));
theme_post_wrapper3(
  array(
   'id' => theme_get_post_id(),
   'class' => theme_get_post_class(),   
   'thumbnail' => theme_get_post_thumbnail(array("size" => array(144, 186))),  
   'title' => '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" rel="bookmark" title="' . strip_tags(get_the_title()) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>',
   'content' => '<h5>Party Affiliation: ' .  $test . '</h5>'
   
  ) 
);

?>

Comment: Sorry, haven't figured out how to post code here yet.

Comment: Do you have your website online? I can try to inspect it. It seems like you need a clearfix after each section.

Comment: The sections are all created dynamically. How or where would you put a clearfix?

Comment: Possibly here `<div class="val-postcontent val-post">`. Like so `<div class="val-postcontent val-post" style="clear:both">` but not really sure if this is a correct place (perpaps on a parent element). BTW this shouldn't be done using inline CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I too belive this is a CSS issue, so it probably belongs on StackExchange instead, but here it goes:

The easiest, quickest (and probably ugliest) fix is to add `<div style="display:block; clear: both;">` *before* each `<div class="val-postcontent val-post">`.

A quick way to make this a little bit cleaner: move the `display:block; clear: both;` into a separate css class, for example `.clearfix {...}`.

edit: I was to quick on the trigger. The div should be added *before* the div

Comment: No problem. In order to get even cleaner, you might want to restructure your HTML some. 

One way could be to wrap the whole sections in boxes, as in one box for "2013 candidates", one for 2014 and so on.  

Another way could be to clean up the CSS of the boxes containing the titles, making them use 100% of the width anyway, and making the browser so it's job of giving them enough space.